# Two restaurants competing in the same region

Tags: optimization, combinations

On a square area $[0,a]\times[0,b]$ exists a continuous function $f(x,y)$. For any $2l$ points in this area and we divide them into two sets, $K=\{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{l}\},M=\{m_{1},\cdots,m_{l}\}$.
Now define
$$M(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{$d((x,y),M)>d((x,y),K)$}\\
f(x,y)&\text{$d((x,y),M)<d((x,y),K)$}\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}f(x,y)&\text{$d((x,y),M)=d((x,y),K)$}
\end{cases}$$
If we arrange the set $K$ first, then $M$, can we guarantee that
$$\iint M(x,y)\text{d}\sigma\geq\frac{1}{2}\iint f(x,y)\text{d}\sigma$$
Or in a vivid way, we may regard $f(x,y)$ as the density of customers. The points are restaurants. Where to have dinner is only determined by the distance. May the initiative restaurant dominate this area or not?

Comment: Do you mean first choose $K$, then can one find $M$ so that the inequality holds? (And I guess that's **M**acDonald and **K**FC).

Comment: I am sorry to make the question ambiguous. Just suppose you are the one leader of these two restaurants and want to set up chain shops in this area, at anywhere possible. The fuction I described above is just a way to judge which part wins. It some kind of game problem I guess.

Comment: By the initiative restaurant do you mean $M$?

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**, one can choose $M$ such that the inequality is true.

For a given set $K=\{k_1,\dots,k_l\}$ we choose
$m_i:=k_i$.
Then, according to the definition of $M(x,y)$, we have
$M(x,y)=\frac12 f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$.
This implies the inequality (in this situation, it is even an equality).